# UIView's animateWithDuration:animations:completion: error

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have the following code

```
-(void) animate:(UIButton*) b withState: (int) state andLastState:(int) last_state {
 if (state < last_state) {
     int stateTemp = state;
     float duration = 1.0 / 30.0;
     [b animateWithDuration: duration
         animations: ^{ [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m1.a000%d.png", state]]; }
    completion: ^{ animate(b, stateTemp++, last_state); }];
     }
}
```

but get an error increment of read-only variable `stateTemp`

I am trying to animate a series of images by setting a `UIButton`s image.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any variable used inside a block is `const` copied.  So really what you've got going on is this:

```
-(void) animate:(UIButton*) b withState: (int) state andLastState:(int) last_state {
if (state < last_state) {
 int stateTemp = state;
 float duration = 1.0 / 30.0;
 [b animateWithDuration: duration
     animations: ^{
      [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m1.a000%d.png", state]];
     }
     completion: ^{
      const int stateTempCopy = stateTemp;
      animate(b, stateTempCopy++, last_state); 
     }
 ];
 }
}
```

The problem is trying to alter a `const` variable.  You can't do that.  Fortunately, there's a way around that, and that's with the `__block` specifier.

Simply change `int stateTemp = state;` to `__block int stateTemp = state;` and you'll be good to go.  (For the documentation on `__block`, check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6))